# Intellij 12 - Can't Reimport Module

Tags: module, intellij-idea

So I ran into a strange problem today. I was having some issues with one of my modules in IntelliJ so I decided I should try blowing it out and rebuilding it from a fresh checkout. I deleted the module from the Project window and then deleted / redownloaded from my file system.

I went back to Intellij and tried importing the module. It took me through the normal steps of selecting options and then seemed to succeed. Only it didn't reappear in my projects window.

I'm not sure what I did, but recreating the whole project isn't an option at this point. I'm hoping someone can shine some light on why Intellij is angry with me.

System Specs:
Mac OSX Mountain Lion
IntelliJ 12.1.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah ha! I think I found the answer.

In my .idea project folder there is a misc.xml. In this file I found

```
<option name="ignoredFiles">
    <set>
        <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/../Projects/.../module/pom.xml />
    </set>
</option>
```

I removed that and also cleaned up some duplicate entries from other areas that pertained to my module and I was able to import again.

IntelliJ is pacified for at least another day!

Comment: @vikingsteve I would assume it was when I deleted it from the Project window. It doesn't make sense but that's the only theory I have. I'd test it, but you know... best not anger the higher powers.

Answer (score 99):

If this is a Gradle module, please check the **.idea** project folder there is a **gradle.xml**

```
  <GradleProjectSettings>
    <option name="distributionType" value="DEFAULT_WRAPPED" />
    <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/xxx" />
    <option name="gradleHome" value="/opt/gradle/gradle-2.13" />
    ......
  </GradleProjectSettings>
```

you should remove this  entry and try to reimport your module

I am using Intellij Idea 2016.1.3, Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.5

Comment: Thanks a lot! IntelliJ's module management trainwreck is just driving me crazy. Today a bunch of modules from elsewhere appeared, and the real ones were gone -- but I wasn't able to re-import for this reason. I feel like spending more time on this kind of silly ide busywork than actually coding... And I really miss Eclipse workspaces... :-/

Comment: Yeah the good comes with the bad sometimes. IntelliJ is almost 4x better than eclipse with gradle projects. but the module management in Eclipse is wayyy better.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 16):

I also had this problem with an SBT module. You can remove the offending module by going to the SBT tool window, right clicking on the module and selecting "Detach external project".

Comment: This saved my day!

Comment: IDEA2017.1 - Similar solution to this answer, `View / Tool Windows / SBT`, then right click on module and `Ignore SBT project`. After that, clean `.sbt/staging` and refresh SBT. Finally, un-ignore the module and the import statements are OK.

Comment: Worked for me as well! This was driving me nuts. IntelliJ not so intelligent when it comes to module management!

Answer (score 10):

This was resolved by going to GRADLE Tab on the project and removing other modules that needs to be reimported.

Answer (score 6):

Click on your Gradle tab, right-click on your project, click on 'Reload Gradle Project'

Comment: Brilliant !  This is the only one that worked for IntelliJ Community Edition 2020.3.2; Gradle tab is available in `View` > `Tool Windows` > `Gradle`

Answer (score 4):

1.delete the file .idea/modules/your module.iml
2.edit the file .idea/gradle.xml del about your module like this:

```
<GradleProjectSettings>
    <option name="distributionType" value="LOCAL" />
    <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/../fs-jycloud-monitor" />
    <option name="gradleHome" value="$USER_HOME$/gradle/gradle-2.14.1" />
    <option name="modules">
      <set>
        <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/../fs-jycloud-monitor" />
      </set>
    </option>
  </GradleProjectSettings>
```

Comment: It's work for me after i delete the *.iml file.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a maven structure, it could be that you ignore the poms after unloading modules. Check this at:

**File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Ignored Files**

Uncheck your modules and try again.

*(If you have many files listed there, just deselect all via Ctrl + A, Space)*

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner solution would probably be to first try `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart....`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a Gradle module. For me the fix was simply to delete this entry from the `.idea/workspace.xml`

```xml
  <component name="ExternalProjectsManager">
    <system id="GRADLE">
      <state>
        <task path="$PROJECT_DIR$/Locations">
          <activation />
        </task>
        <projects_view>
          <tree_state>
            <expand>
              <path>
                <item name="" type="6a2764b6:ExternalProjectsStructure$RootNode" />
                <item name="locations" type="f1a62948:ProjectNode" />
              </path>
              <path>
                <item name="" type="6a2764b6:ExternalProjectsStructure$RootNode" />
                <item name="locations" type="f1a62948:ProjectNode" />
                <item name="Run Configurations" type="7b0102dc:RunConfigurationsNode" />
              </path>
            </expand>
            <select />
          </tree_state>
        </projects_view>
      </state>
    </system>
  </component>
```