# "java: cannot find symbol" in IntelliJ but gradle builds

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm building a [java project](https://github.com/blk-io/erc20-rest-service) with IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5 (Community Edition) with the following errors:
[image: IntelliJ errors]

However, if I build with `./gradlew build --x test`, it is OK. I've tried all methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132003/getting-cannot-find-symbol-in-java-project-in-intellij), but still no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the [gralde integration in intelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html).

Comment: Delete `.idea` directory and reimport the project from Gradle. If the issue persists, report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) and the sample project to reproduce.

Comment: If you have already integrated with Gradle then you may have to invalidate your caches. To do that I believe you got to File -> invalidate caches and restart. This will force IntelliJ to reindex the project allowing it to identify symbols.

Comment: @Turing85 I tried, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I tried, but it didn't work. Will report as a bug.

Comment: @vandench I tried invalidating, unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Turn on "Preference" | "Build, Execution, Deployment" | "Compiler" | "Annotation Processors" | "Enable annotation processing".

Answer (score 1):

1 - Check if Anotation Processing is enable in both 'Settings' and 'Default Settings' windows.

2 - Check if Lombok Plugin is installed and updated.

3 - Remove ALL generated folders from your project (.idea, .gradle, gradle, build, out..)

4 - Rerun Gradle Build.

This worked for me today when the Idea build was working but the Gradle run kept giving me errors.