# Cannot find symbol when calling constructor

Tags: java, jcreator

When I try to run this code:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Employee employee1 = new Employee("John", 5545, "R&D", "QA Lead", 50000);

    }
}
```

I get an error saying "error: cannot find symbol"

The Employee class code I'm trying to run:

```
public class Employee 
{

    private int ID;
    private double salary;
    private String name, department, designation;

    public Employee(){}

    public Employee(String userName, int userID, String userDepartment, String userDesignation, double userSalary)
    {
        name = userName;
        ID = userID;
        department = userDepartment;
        designation = userDesignation;
        salary = userSalary;
    }
```

The Employee class has various setters and getters for all the variables afterwords.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace (It should say "cannot find symbol:" and then give which symbol it cannot find)

Comment: 50000 is not a double

Comment: Cannot find symbol could mean that the class isn't found.

Comment: All it says is cannot find symbol.http://prntscr.com/ksu8td

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error

Comment: is `Employee` class accessible to class `main`?

Comment: What is the line 5? @Chris, As per the screenshot its an error in that line

Comment: It's the line where I create employee1 in main

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding the project

Comment: @TheScientificMethod What do you mean? I have both classes saved under the same file so they should be accessible

Comment: @Chris i got it, you can not have two public classes on the same file.

Comment: Try changing the value of salary to a double variable, also try removing extra spaces in that line if any. If you copied that code try typing it and tell us if any of the following solved the problem? Also as mentioned by @TheScientificMethod you cannot have two public classes

Comment: @TheScientificMethod So how do I fix that? Do I change one of the constructors from public? Also, editing salary to a double didn't fix it.

Comment: @Chris change from `public class Employee` to `class Employee` and try.

Comment: If you have 2 classes declared within a single `.java` file, make sure that only one is `public`. f they are in separate packages, make sure you imported the class.

Comment: @TheScientificMethod They are two separate files in the same folder, not two classes in the same file. Sorry for the mixup, the solutions didn't fix the error.

Comment: @Chris sorry, please check whether the file name `Employee.java` is same as class name `Employee` aslo you are missing the last `}`

Comment: @TheScientificMethod Yes, the file name is the same as the class name, and I left off the last } because there are more setters and getters in the class before the end

Comment: you are missing the last `}` in the code, is that unintentionally ?

Comment: Yeah, I edited my last comment to show why

Comment: what's  the utility to use setters and getters  inside  ur code (u may have an error 
 while declaring them ) try to delete  them all and  rerun the main class.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to open your project settings and recreate folders for source code - define src directory so intellij can recognize. 
See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132003/getting-cannot-find-symbol-in-java-project-in-intellij)