# What is the return type of Collectors.groupingBy(...)?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `MultiValueMap<String, String>` and let's say I want to group it by the key's length.

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = // Some defined MultiValueMap ... 

map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> {
    return x.getKey().length();
}));
```

The problem is, I can't figure out the `return` type of the above statement.
I've tried e.g.

```
Map<String, Set<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>>> groupped = map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> {
    return x.getKey().length();
}));
```

But then I'll get `x.getKey()` cannot be resolved.

Comment: You can see the return type of any method in its Javadoc ...

Comment: `MultiValueMap` from where?

Comment: Don’t you use an IDE which can insert the variable declaration for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should return `Map<Integer, List<Map.Entry<String, String>>>` instead of  `Map<String, Set<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>>>`.

note the `String` key and the `Set<...>` values you've included above, it should be an `Integer` key and a `List<...>` as values as this overload of [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) you're using returns a:

> `Map<K, List<T>>` whose keys are the values resulting from applying
>   the classification function to the input elements, and whose
>   corresponding values are Lists containing the input elements which map
>   to the associated key under the classification function.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that also. But it always lead to cannot resolve method `x.getKey()`

Comment: @blueFalcon cannot replicate it on my IDE unfortunately.

Comment: What IDE are you using, and can you post a snippet of that code somewhere?

Comment: @blueFalcon IntelliJ IDEA. [here is an ideone example](https://ideone.com/OGi9M9), note that I am using a `Map<String, String>` in the code instead of `MultiValueMap` (as I don't know where that is from) but the solution above should work regardless as long as you can guarantee `MultiValueMap` has a `getKey()` method (which I'd assume it should).

Comment: `MultiValueMap` is from [Spring framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html), which extends `Map<K, List<V>>` and has `getKey()` method. It's bugging because the compiler cannot resolve the `getKey` method whenever I try to assign a variable to it, otherwise it works.

Comment: @blueFalcon seems strange, not experienced something as such before, what IDE are you using?

Comment: Same as yours, IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate @Aomine

Comment: @blueFalcon unfortunately, I've not used spring framework before (I am mostly a .NET guy outside of StackOverflow) and I cannot see what's going on in your screen so cannot really be of much help. just try searching on the web, I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132003/getting-cannot-find-symbol-in-java-project-in-intellij) where people were posting their solutions to similar problems.